# How to merge 2 files just if the first field is a line with a date

Tags: bash

I have 2 files,

```
file1.txt                      file2.txt
---------                      ---------
2-                             14/07/2020 00:00:00 some text
3-                             15/07/2020 00:00:01 some text
1-                             some text
5-                             some text
                               24/07/2020 00:10:01 some text
                               some text
                               30/07/2020 00:20:01 some text
```

I am looking to create the next file:

```
finalResult.txt
---------------
2-14/07/2020 00:00:00 some text
3-15/07/2020 00:00:01 some text
some text
some text
1-24/07/2020 00:10:01 some text
some text
5-30/07/2020 00:20:01 some text
```

I tried to use paste command

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt > finalResult.txt
```

But it gives me wrong results

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Try: `paste file1 <(grep '^[0-9]' file2)` if `sometext` doesn't begin with a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following perl one-liner replaces newlines (not followed by pattern `\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}`), by non printable character ascii 1.

```
perl -0777pe 's~\n(?!\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})~\x1~g' file2.txt
```

So, assuming there is no character 1, the command can be

```
paste -d '' file1.txt <(perl -0777pe 's~\n(?!\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})~\x1~g' file2.txt) | tr '\1' '\n'
```

or can also be done with GNU sed, changing newlines when line doesn't start with a number

```
paste -d '' file1.txt <(sed -zr 's~\n([^0-9])~\x1\1~g' file2.txt) | tr '\1' '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Thats help me:

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to upvote and accept if it answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is easily answered with a quick awk:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[FNR]=$0;next}/^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}/{$0=a[++c] $0}1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The answer consists out of 3 parts:

- **`(NR==FNR){a[FNR]=$0;next}`:** When we read the first file (`NR==FNR`) store the record/line in an array which we index by the record number `FNR` and move to the next record (`next`)
- **`/^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}/{$0=a[++c] $0}:`** When we notice that the record starts with a string of the form `xx/yy/zzzz` where `x`, `y`, and `z` are decimal digits, prepend the corresponding record of file1. We keep track of this using a counter `c` which we increment every time we find such match. (`$0=a[++c] $0`). Note, we could improve the regex to properly match the date-time format, but this seems overkill here:
- **`1`**: perform the default action, i.e. `print $0`

**If**, for whatever reason, your input file could contain strings which accidently represent something similar to a date, but could be wrong (e.g. replace `some text` by `29-02-2021`, then you have to do some smarter stuff and actually validate the date-time format. With GNU awk you can do this in the following way:

```
awk 'function is_date(d,t) {
       split(d,b,/[^0-9]); 
       return (d" "t)==strftime(mktime(b[3]" "b[1]" "b[2]" "t),"%m/%d/%Y %T")
     }
    (NR==FNR){a[FNR]=$0;next}(is_date($1,$2)){$0=a[++c] $0}1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

**General comment:** always use the ISO date-format of the form `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS` it makes your life really easy!